# Best way to change language at runtime

Tags: android

I'm developing an app and I have added a settings screen to allow users to change the language of the string literals of the app.

In the `onCreate` method of the activities I use the following code:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, 0);
String language = settings.getString(PREF_LANGUAGE, "en");
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
Locale.setDefault(locale);Configuration config = new     Configuration();config.locale = locale;getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

It works fine, but `config.locale` and `getResources().updateConfiguration` are deprecated.

How should I implement that functionality avoiding the use of these commands?

I've read some posts in SO, but all of them suggest the usage of `@SupressWarnings`. Does not exist another way to solve the problem?

Comment: so, are you looking for an option to let, at runtime, english OS phones change the strings to spanish, then german, then portuguese, then english again? why? I ask the why, because this will be quite complicated

Comment: The app shows literals in the language of the phone by default, but there is a settings screen. One of the preferences allows to select another language, an at that point a listener detects that change and the new value for the language is stored. The code I've posted works, but it has two deprecated instructions. I would like to do it with other non-deprecated instructions